# If two add-ons use the same application handler, is there a way to see (or force) which add-on executes first?

Tags: python, scripting

I wrote an add-on which uses `frame_change_pre` as an application handler.  Other add-ons may also use `frame_change_pre` as their application handler.

**If two add-ons use the same application handler, is there a way to see (or force) which add-on executes first?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callable is been called in sequence where in `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre`

As a easy snippet here:

```py
import bpy
#pre and post running seq are same direction
fcp = bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre 
fcp.clear() #clear the list for testing only

def myfunction(*args):
    print("My first func")

fcp.append(myfunction)
fcp.append(lambda *args:print("Second lambda"))

print(fcp)
```

After excute, change 1 frame and the console output:

```py
[<function myfunction at 0x000002A5E4C37A68>, <function <lambda> at 0x000002A5E4BF4F78>]
My first func
Second lambda
```

So you can some how insert your code at the begin of list:

- `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.insert(0, your_function)`

Or determine where your function is in the right position:

```py
my_index = fcp.index(myfunction)
fcp.pop(index = my_index)
fcp.insert(0, myfunction)
```

Comment: You might need to separate a function button to check whether your add-on's calls is in the right position and let user determine whether to rearrange the position.

Comment: Thank you, very informative! Will look into this for my situation!

Comment: @zippy thanks for letting me know that, BTW that `list` should be read-only, eg. you can't assign a new list to it, only modify it in-place.